# Jstring to TCHAR Array Unicode

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I received from an Java App a JString with a drive letter.
I have to pass this to a TCHAR Array to a native Lib. Any idea how to put the JString to
and Unicode TCHAR Array? What I found is

```
const TCHAR *drive = env->GetStringUTFChars(lDevice, JNI_FALSE);
```

But I do not need const `TCHAR *`, I need `TCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JNI, but:

```
const char *drive = env->GetStringUTFChars(lDevice, JNI_FALSE);
const TCHAR letter = drive[0];
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(lDevice);
```

Note that `drive[0]` is a `const char` but will be converted to either a `char` or a `const wchar_t`, both are fine.